# nginx (+ passenger) doesn't seem to run on port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, nginx, passenger, homebrew

I have nginx (*with* ***passenger***) installed on my user account (*via* ***homebrew***). For a few hours I thought the thing just refuses to work, as I couldn't get any Rails3 application to respond on a simple nginx-declared location. After much deliberation (*AKA trial-and-error*) I came to conclusion that it does work, but refuses to use port 80.

I know, that a **homebrew** installation is a per user installation, thus it should not be able to run on root-only ports (*ie. ports 1024 and below*), but **homebrew itself** (*and various sources on the net*) suggest that simply running the server via `sudo nginx` would suffice to allow it to use port 80.

These are the important files of the configuration that **does** work:

#### /etc/hosts:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       doomhub.local localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

#### /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /Users/ellmo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.18/;
    passenger_ruby /Users/ellmo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  logs/access.log;  #main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

        server {
            server_name doomhub.local;
            listen 8080;
            root /Users/ellmo/rails/doomhub/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
            passenger_use_global_queue on;
            rails_env development;
        }
}
```

When I change the application's server port to `80`, I naturally will - upon restart - receive a:

`nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)`

...but when I `sudo` it, the error won't show, the process will start with `root` as its owner. However opening `http://doomhub.local` in the browser returns nothing (*well, technically it's a "browser could not resolve the address" error, but I get no other errors, no nginx error*). I get no logs, no nothing.

When I change the listening port back to 8080 (or anything else) it works like a charm when I run it as a regular user... but then I really want to use `http://doomhub.local` in my browser rather than `http://doomhub.local:8080`.

Is there anything that would block OSX apps from listening on port 80, that I'm missing? As you can see I **CAN** use it, so there's no other process in the way. It just doesn't listen to anyhting.

Is there any way to treat `8080` in the browser as a "normal" **http** port?

## EDIT:

Specifying passenger users as [Jan Schejbal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1939031/jan-schejbal) suggested didn't solve the issue for me, after a while I ended up creating **rvm** wrappers for passenger (*rather than allowing it to use clear ruby binaries*) as described in this great post:

http://everydayrails.com/2010/09/13/rvm-project-gemsets.html

Thanks to creating a **passenger/bundler-only rvm wrapper** I managed to get the application running when I start nginx as **root**. I can specify both root-only and user-allowed listening ports (*ie. I tested both 8080 and 81*) and the application is served fine even with all the gems that are **NOT** related to the wrapper binary. Yet...

...still I get absolutely nothing on port 80.

Comment: What happens if you use other privileged ports, e.g. 81?

Comment: Ran it under 81, and here are some new things I learned. First of all it opens in the browser when I specify `doomhub.local:81` address and displays **passenger's** "gem-missing" error. When I went back to change the port to `8080` again and then tried running nginx as root (*even though it would work as user now*) and I got the same error. This leads me to conclusion, that the problem lies within **root** user not being able to access any gems in the app (_even though the path to **rvm ruby** is given_). I probably have to find a way to show **root** that he needs to use **rvm** gems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### proper diagnosis

Hah!
I completely forgot I had **pow** installed on my system. I know I had it disabled altogether before I started playing with **nginx**, but that was not enough. As you may know **pow** is a zero-configuration server tool that automatically creates localhost domain - this also means that it... "appropriates" port 80, which you can see if you type:

`sudo ipfw list`

This should return something like:

```
00100 fwd 127.0.0.1,20559 tcp from any to me dst-port 80 in
65535 allow ip from any to any
```

...which clearly shows that any ip connection on port 80 is forwarded to 20559 (***pow's*** *port*)

### solution

What we want do do now is to delete this port-80 forwarding information and use some other port in it's place. That will allow us to easily host development servers for multiple rails applications (**each with its own gemset and configuration**) and proxy them through **passenger's** upstreams.

[There's a great write-up on how to achieve the first part of this task](http://leonid.shevtsov.me/en/how-to-install-nginx-over-pow-in-os-x). To me it seems like simply changing the **ipfw** entries manually would suffice, but I went with the blog entry. If you do this - make sure you use proper **pow** install/uninstall scripts from [pow's manual](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_1); for example I had to fully **un**-install pow **before** the installation script would successfully compile.

Comment: Apart from Pow, also local-tld (Pow without the rack-part) from hood.ie does a similar trick. I had no useful ipfw rules, so could simply do a flush to remove the local-tld rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that running as root causes permission problems, causing the app not to work. Have you tried the `PassengerUserSwitching` option together with `PassengerUser` and  `PassengerGroup`?

Edit: Missed the "could not resolve address" error. Still try the above (Passenger is weird sometimes), but also try running a netstat to see if the port is correctly bound.

Comment: I need to read about this user switching thingy, I hope it can resolve my problem with root accessing user's rvm rubies and gems.